# Crystal Reports Check All dependencies of a report

Tags: crystal-reports

Problem: As you may know report wizards and reports inside crystal reports have a Many to Many relationship. This makes reporting tricky as one report relies on:

1. 1 or more reportwizards
2. 0 or more subreports

and these main reports can rely on multiple sub reports and those sub reports rely on multiple report wizards.

So is there any way to catalog the reports and their dependencies?

example:

```
**ReportWizard Name**        **Report 1**          **Report 2**     ....  
Billing                      clientsReport           EmployeeReport
```

AND/OR in reverse...

```
          ReportWizard1 Name    ReportWizard2 Name   ....  
Report 1  
Report 2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Report wizards are part of the report designer - they aren't dependencies at all.

Subreports are saved as part of the report file (even though they may have been imported from another existing report), so they aren't dependencies of the main report as such - they *are* (part of) the report.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to **Database->Set Datasource Location**, you can see everything you're looking for:

[image]